# How to get Renamed, Deleted, and Added Columns of the Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table in a database (TblExample) that contains three columns:

- Name
- Age
- City

After some time, someone added one extra column (**Country**) or deleted a column (**City**) or renamed a column (**Name** to **FirstName**).

Now, how can I determine the added, deleted or renamed column of the table?

Comment: Which RDMBS/SQL are you using? Which API are you using to query it?

Comment: Ideally, (and also in not so ideal situations), all scripts, especially schema changes, should be maintained in version control software. That way you have good traceability.

Answer (score 1):

From the tag I see you are using SQL, you can check out DDL triggers:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-security/csidba-finding-out-who-made-schema-changes/